# Why does my Custom UserControl's dependency property not work with dynamically binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

My Custom UserControl's dependency property will bind correctly if the value is statically defined in the XAML calling it, like this:

```
TextBoxText="myName"
```

but not if the value is bound dynamically itself:

```
TextBoxText="{Binding ItemTypeIdCode}"
```

There is my full Code.

Custom UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="TestUserControl.UserControl1"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
x:Name="UserControl" Height="22" Width="282">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyName, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
</Grid>
```

Custom UserControl Code:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

    public string TextBoxText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
    }
```

In my Main Window XAML :

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Button" Height="78" Margin="0,0,93,112" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="94" Click="MyButtonClick"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,112" Width="192">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="286,37,56,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" TextBoxText="{Binding MyName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In my Main Window Code :

```
    private void MyButtonClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> MyName = new List<string>();
        MyName.Add("Name 1");
        MyName.Add("Name 2");
        MyName.Add("Name 3");
        MyListBox.ItemsSource = MyName;
    }
```

This Code Successfully add my Custom UserControl as ListBoxItem in ListBox But Problem it is not display any text which i Binding.

I don`t understand where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is it just a typo in your post here that you've got `<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MyName, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>` instead of `<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TextBoxText, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>` ?

Comment: I do that but my bro it`s not working.

Comment: @Vero009: I do not think you should call everyone *"bro"*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the `DataContext` of the UserControl to itself, all bindings will then try to find the path on the UserControl, that is why you should not set the `DataContext` on UserControls.

You should see a binding error in the Output window of Visual Studio saying something like:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ItemTypeIdCode' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl1' (Name='UserControl')'. ...

Comment: This always trips me up. I always first think its because i've got two bindings on the same property. Then I have that "smacks forehead" moment. Good call H.B.

Comment: First thing to do on those questions: Search for the DataContext

Comment: Yes bro i saw that binding error in the Output window of Visual Studio. Now can you tell me how can i Solve it ?

Comment: @Vero009: Err, to quote my answer *"you should not set the DataContext on UserControls"*